# Laravel withQueryString does not exist after calling paginate method on query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::withQueryString does
> not exist.

when i write this code it gives this error

blade;

```
<div class="float-right">{{ $modeller->withQueryString()->links()}}</div>
```

controller;

```
public function index(){

    $modeller = Modeller::query();
    $koleksiyonlar = Koleksiyon::all();
    $modelistler = Modelist::all();
    $uretim_sorumlulari = Uretim_sorumlusu::all();

    if(request('model_kodu')){
        
        $modeller = $modeller->where('ModelKodu', 'LIKE', "%".request('model_kodu')."%");
    }
    if(request('koleksiyon_id')){

        $modeller = $modeller->where('koleksiyon_id', 'LIKE', "%".request('koleksiyon_id')."%");
    }
    if(request('uretim_sorumlusu_id')){

        $modeller = $modeller->where('UretimSor', 'LIKE', "%".request('uretim_sorumlusu_id')."%");
    }if(request('modelist_id')){

    $modeller = $modeller->where('modelist_id', 'LIKE', "%".request('modelist_id')."%");
}

    $modeller = $modeller->paginate(18);


    return view('kumas.index',compact('modeller','koleksiyonlar','modelistler','uretim_sorumlulari'));
}
```

Comment: Hope following is correct way to use it.

$modeller = $modeller->paginate(18)->withQueryString();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `paginate` method, runs an implicit `get` on your query result.
try to use `withQueryString` instead of `paginate`.
example:

```
$modeller->withQueryString()->paginate(18);
```

but from your use case I suggest to use this in your view, instead of query string, this will add everything came from query string to your links:

```
{{ $users->appends($_GET)->links() }}
```

### More Details on the pagination & Query String params

the page, offset, ... and everything paginate needs, would append automatically to paginate function without any effort.
you only need to explicitly `->appends($_GET)` when you have some filtering parameters in your `$_GET` and want to preserve them in the following requests, when user clicks the **next page** or **previous page**

Comment: Thank you
How can I write this query more regularly? is there any other solution to the query I use?

Comment: nice to hear that, if my answer helped you you can **accept it** & **vote for it**

Comment: @onur I have added more detail about when you need  add the `->append($_GET)` to your links

Answer (score 0):

to expand on @Abilogos answer, I think it is better to use `Request::except('page')` method, which return an array of query parameter except the `page` parameter

in your blade view:

```
{{ $users->appends(\Request::except('page')->links() }}
```